# Maximising radius of a circle inside a 2D shape

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I'm given a set of inequalities which define constraints of a geometric shape. For simplicity, let's assume its a 2D object, say a triangle. I want to find the maximum radius $r$ of a circle $c$, that fits inside the triangle without violating the given inequalities. I'm using linear programming to find $r$.

The solution is: Having an objective function that maximizes $r$, while adding the euclidian norm of the coefficients vector to the inequalities with $r$ as a factor:
$$ a_0x_0+a_1x_1+r\|a\|_2\le d$$

I'm struggling to grasp the intuition why this works. Hence the question, what's the intuition behind the solution and why does it work?

Comment: You seem to assume that the shape is convex. Is it true? Is it a consequence of the shape being defined by a set of inequalities?

Comment: Yes, the shape for the example is convex. Sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: The equation can be rewritten as
$$a_0x_0+a_1x_1+r\|a\|_2\le d\quad\iff\quad r \le \frac{d - (a_0x_0 + a_1x_1)}{\|a\|_2}$$
The RHS on the right is the distance between the center and the line of corresponding constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move from your coordinate $x$ in any direction $z$, where the length of $z$ is less than $r$, i.e., $||z||_2 \leq r$, you still want the constraint to hold. In other words $a^T(x+d) \leq d ~\forall ||z||_2 \leq r$. Write as $a^Tx + a^Tz \leq d ~\forall ||z||_2 \leq r$. The inner product $a^Tz$ is maximized by a vector $z$ which is parallel to $a$, i.e., $z = r\frac{a}{||a||_2}$ has the sought direction and correct length. Plug in this $z$ and it leads to $a^Tx + a^T r\frac{a}{||a||_2} \leq d$ which simplifies to $a^Tx + r||a||_2 \leq d$.

FYI, you are computing the Chebychev circle.

Comment: How you simplify $r\frac{a}{||a||_2}$ to get $r{||a||_2}$ I don't quite understand.

Comment: Added the final step explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as decrasing $d$ by $r\|a\|_2$, ie. pushing the limit by $r$ units "inside", which turns the constraint from one for the circle perimeter to a constraint for the circle center. (Of course this works so simple only for convex shapes)